# Update Solana in Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04

Sorry I'm a Linux n00b.

I have version 1.9.5 of Solana running in Ubuntu (a new VM).

I thought:

```
sudo apt update
```

and

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

would update all the installed packages in Linux, but when I run these then type 'Solana --version' into the Terminal it still shows 1.9.5 - an old version.

Sorry I'm new to Linux, I've searched a lot on Google but I just find the above commands without explaining the problem here.

How can I update all packages and how do I update an individual one - including Solana here?

Is Solana (and is every app in Linux) installed via a package that's upated with `sudo apt update`?

Thanks

Comment: sorry i typed 'ubuntu' in the tags and it replaced it with 14.04. I guess 22.04 is latest? I'll fix the tag.

Comment: How did you install Solana?

Comment: "*Is Solana (and is every app in Linux) installed via a package that's upated with sudo apt update?*" No. There are a dozen ways to install software. Some are easy. Some are hard. Apt is most common, but used for but a single one of those dozen methods -- the use of deb packages. Apt cannot see or affect any of the others. Hence @FedKad's very reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default Apt packages incuded with Ubuntu are limited to the current stable release at the time your Ubuntu version is released. 14.04 is quite old now so the apt package incuded is likely out of date.

Assuming I have the right software, Solana's documentation lists alternate installation methods [here](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools)

Essentially just run this command and it will run through the install script `sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.10.32/install)"`

Comment: Thanks
Does that command install a package? Are packages the only way to install things in Linux? If it's a package can't I just use apt update? Sorry for n00b questions.

Comment: Also how can I just install or update to the 'latest' version of solana, without specifying the version?

Comment: I typed 'ubuntu' in tags and it replaced with 14.04, I'm not on that version I'm on 24.04. I've updated the tag thx.

Comment: @niico you're living in the future! 22.04 is the latest Ubuntu version currently. Apt packages are not the only way to install softare in Linux, Ubuntu also uses a system called Snap, there is also AppImage, Flatpak etc. Some software run their own install scripts that just copies files around which amounts to installation, looking briefly at the Solana installer I think this is what that script does.

Comment: @niico Normally running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` would install the latest version of all software provided by apt packages, this might not always be the latest version of the software available and sometimes if you visit the software's website they will give an alternate install method. Solana isn't providing an Apt Package for their software so it's up to them on how their software is updated and whether they supply a method of installing the latest version or if you just have to provide a specific version each time.

Comment: Thanks - so using apt is optional - some software providers will just make you use their installer instead, probably through curl, and not support apt packages then?

Comment: Aren't I living in the present lol?

Comment: Sorry meant to type 22.04

Comment: I think the conclusion is not all software is installed using apt.

Comment: @niico yes you are correct, Apt is optional and one of many installation methods on Linux, it's very popular for Debian-based operating systems like Ubuntu.